# Magento2 - Hide price if value is 0

Tags: magento2

I want to hide the price if value is 0.
For simple products I use this code and it works:

**Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml**

```
 <?php if($block->getDisplayValue() !== 0): ?>
```

But for config. products I know I have to change this file:

**module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml**

```
<?php if($block->getDisplayValue() !== 0): ?> // doesn't work
<?php if($finalPriceModel->getAmount() !== 0): ?> // doesn't work
<?php echo $finalPriceModel->getAmount(); ?> //  works 0, 1.8, 20.5
```

How can I get the value  and use it in a if-statement?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had to hide the price if it is 0 on categorie pages and I used this code in the if-statement `$_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getValue()`

The whole part of my code was:

```
<?php if ($_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getValue()): ?>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It hides the price if it is 0, but not only for configurable products.
It is not exactly what you asked for, but I hope this could be helpful though.

Answer (score 0):

This code is work for me.

```
<?php 
if ($_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getValue() == 0) {
        echo "Contact Us";
} else {
        echo $block->getProductPrice($_product);
}
?>
```